# JSON Value failed

Tags: iphone, json

I am fetching data from server into my iPhone app.

But it shows the exception

> -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 \"Valid fragment, but not JSON\" UserInfo=0x6e9b460 {NSLocalizedDescription=Valid fragment, but not JSON}"

Any Solution.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? The JSON seems to be invalid. Solution: Create valid JSON.

Comment: Please post a sample of what is returned by the server; is it even valid JSON?

Comment: @etienne It Returns the character 1

Comment: Some iOS JSON parsers (eg. SBJson) work only when the root is an object or an array.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data should be in this format use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check the json format